# Detect if the left mouse button is being held down outside the form

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I like to develop small tools for making life easier when working around your computer, and I figured an autoclicker would be my next target. I already have the clicking method, GUI, and such, but the one thing that I am missing is the ability to toggle the autoclicker on and off. I have set up a hotkey such as Shift+F, Control+D, or any variation of that (customizable in the form of course), but I really want to be able to just hold down the left mouse button to click.

Here's my idea in Pseudocode: (LMB as leftmousebutton)

```
if LMB isDown then tmrClick.toggle (on)
if LMB isUp then tmrClick.toggle (off)
```

I have created something similar before with low level mouse hooks, but it was rather messy and dysfunctional. Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated as it has been forever and I still cannot find a viable solution to this problem.

Comment: I am intrigued, I'll bite... What is an autoclicker?

Comment: Well, a lot of times in different games it is important to click your mouse quickly. I wanted to make it so that you could easily do that without the stress of actually clicking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

https://globalmousekeyhook.codeplex.com/

Even the library be in C#, you can use it in VB.NET.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll give it a look and if it works out I'll mark this as a solution :)

Comment: Worked! Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: :) I'm glad for you.